# Nested IF Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to perform a calculation, in column D of a spreadsheet, that depends on a string in column K. The calculations required are, if column K says:

```
 "Income then Principal ", then perform: (E2 + F2) - H2  
 "50 50 ",                 then perform: ((H2/2) - E2))+((H2/2) - F2))  
 "100% Principal ",        then perform: F2 - H2  
 "100% Income ",           then return:  $0.00
```

I wrote the nested IF formula shown below. It works for "Income then Principal" and "100% Income", but I get a return of `FALSE` for "50 50 " and a `#VALUE!` error for "100% Principal ".  I think I have a syntax error in my formula but I'm having trouble isolating it.

```
=IF(K3="Income then Principal ",(E3+F3)-H3,IF(K3="100% Principal ",F2-H2,IF(K3="50 50",((H2/2)-E2+(H2/2)-F2),IF(K3="100% Income ",))))
```

Comment: Your last `if()` is incomplete - `IF(K3="100% Income ",)`

Comment: confirm the trailing spaces in your formula match the cell values in K3, e.g., `"50 50 "` vs. `"50 50"`?

Comment: Nested ifs can get complicated quickly: you can sometimes simplify this a bit by using something along the lines of `=CHOOSE(MATCH(K1,{"A","B","C"}),"Value if A","Value if B", "Value if C")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
=IF(K3="Income then Principal ",(E3+F3)-H3,IF(K3="100% Principal ",F2-H2,IF(K3="50 50 ",((H2/2)-E2+(H2/2)-F2),IF(K3="100% Income ",0,))))
```

Comment: This worked - =IF(K3="Income then Principal ",(E3+F3)-H3,IF(K3="100% Principal ",F3-H3,IF(K3="50 50 ",((H3/2)-E3+(H3/2)-F3),IF(K3="100% Income ",)))) @pnuts good point about referencing row2 and row3 simultaneously, row2 is my header row so that was an error on my end.  Writing this out really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Numbering  the options (say 1 to 4 in ColumnM in order as above) would allow at least a much shorter formula:

```
=CHOOSE(M3,E3+F3-H3,H3-E3-F3,F3-H3,0)
```

(The above might not have all the + and - in the right places! but troubleshooting is should be easy.)